# Assembler: "Function Call" assembler code produced by VC++

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, function-call

I am by all means no assembler expert, and my knowledge on this topic is rather shallow, but I was curious on what the Microsoft VC++ Compiler does in a simple function call that does nothing else but returning a value.

Let us have the following function:

```
unsigned long __stdcall someFunction ( void * args) {
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I know that with `__stdcall` calling convention the CALLEE is responsible for stack unwinding, and with `__cdecl` the CALLER of the function takes care of this. But for this example I would like to stick to the former.

With an non-optimized debug build I saw that the following output is being produced:

```
unsigned long __stdcall someFunction (void * args) {
00A31730  push        ebp  
00A31731  mov         ebp,esp  
00A31733  sub         esp,0C0h  
00A31739  push        ebx  
00A3173A  push        esi  
00A3173B  push        edi  
00A3173C  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
00A31742  mov         ecx,30h  
00A31747  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00A3174C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
    return 0;
00A3174E  xor         eax,eax  
}
00A31750  pop         edi  
00A31751  pop         esi  
00A31752  pop         ebx  
00A31753  mov         esp,ebp  
00A31755  pop         ebp  
00A31756  ret         4
```

I would thank anyone to explain this snippet of code for me if possible. I know that the `xor` statement actually resets the `eax` register to produce the zero return value. Also the `ret 4` is self-explanatory to me. I think the `edi`, `esi` and `ebx` registers are pushed before and popped after to save the original state, so that the function can use them freely maybe. But for the rest - I have no clue.

Any answer is very much appreciated! :)

Thanks!

Comment: It will entirely remove the function since it doesn't do anything useful.  There is not much point at looking at the code that's generated by the Debug configuration, most of what you posted is there because of the /RTC option.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that :) It really is just a question about the logic itself, how the VC compiler builds a raw function construct in this case - even if it's being dropped during optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're asking what these lines do:

```
00A3173C  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
00A31742  mov         ecx,30h  
00A31747  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00A3174C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]
```

In Visual C++ debugging runtime library, uninitialized stack memory is initialized to contain `0xCC` bytes. This is what these instructions do.

At the beginning of the ASM code, there is the instruction `sub esp,0C0h` that allocates `0xC0` bytes for the stack. However, there is no local variables used in this function, so where does this come from? It's for Edit+Continue support: you're able to add local variables and continue debugging.

The `0xCC` opcode means the `INT 3` x86 assembly instruction, so if you try to execute that code (accidentally due to a bug), the program will throw an INT 3 exception which will be handled by the debugger or OS. So it's not just some random value.

Comment: While you're correct in what the code does I'm not sure about the INT 3 part. Do you have a link to that information?

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far. I came across these `0xCC` bytes quite a lot when running into access violations, and already have read about INT 3 a few days ago and how debuggers use them. But, if possible, could you be a bit more specific about these four lines? Why's is `edi` loaded with `[ebp-0C0h]` ? This value also seems not to be random. Or why is `ecx` filled with `0x30`? I don't want to be a pain in the bottom, sorry my wording, but I'd love to have know a little bit more about it :)

Comment: The missing ingredient is Edit+Continue support.  The Debug build over-allocates the stack space so you can add local variables and continue debugging.